# Call sp within another sp

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2000

I have an sp named 'FolderSttructure'.It returns the following result -

### FolderID

1
2
3
4

I have to call the above sp 'FolderSttructure' inside another sp named 'SearchFolder' and insert the result of first sp in to a temperory table.

Is it possible?

If yes how can we do that?

Answer (score 3):

Yse, you can do it like this:

```
CREATE TABLE #ATempTable
(
FolderID INTEGER
)

INSERT #ATempTable
EXECUTE FolderSttructure
...
```

Comment: +1 Beat me to the punch!1 :-) Just one thing, the temp table must be exact match of whatever the SP returns. In this case, i think the FolderID may not be an integer. In his example it Looks like a string "1 2 3 4" maybe of concatenated values. Or maybe its just misleading formatting

Comment: I think this answer is not only the best one here so far, but it is also absolutely correct, and I would recommend Adu to accept it.